# Выражение «как такого»?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вопрос:
Существует ли в русском языке выражение «как такого»?

К примеру:
Как такого я сегодня ещё не завтракал.

---

Спасибо за информацию. Немного сомневаюсь как будет правильно применить это выражение в следующем предложении: Как такого, неизвестно, стоял ли Иисус на стене буквального храма, или это было лишь видение. Или всё же: Как такового, неизвестно, стоял ли Иисус на стене буквального храма, или это было лишь видение. Буду благодарен!

Answer (score 4):

Видимо, вам в искажённом виде запомнилось выражение "**как такового**", употребляемое чаще всего при отрицании чего-либо, выраженного *существительным*. Если адаптировать его к вашему примеру, получилось бы так:

> **Как такового** завтрака у меня сегодня **не было** (наспех перекусил).

Здесь смысл выражения в том, что завтраком (в строгом смысле) это нельзя было бы назвать, это противоречит определению понятия "завтрак" (это был не завтрак **как таковой** = это не то, что принято называть завтраком). *Как таковой* буквально означает *взятый сам по себе*, рассматриваемый абстрактно на предмет "это или что-то другое".

Answer (score 1):

ТАКОВОЙ,  прил. Офиц. Употр. вместо существительного, упомянутого выше. Не купили билета **за отсутствием такового**. Не встретили поезд по причине неприбытия такового.

<**Как таковой**, в функц. опр. **Взятый сам по себе, безотносительно к чему-л. другому.** Вопрос важен **как таковой**. Любовь **как таковая** меня не интересует.

Возможные синонимы: ***как таковой*** - это ***сам по себе, в обычном понимании этого слова.***

Примеры:

Работы **как таковой** вообще нет.

Я сам неоднократно выступал по поводу того, что **как таковой** Союз писателей изжил себя.

Вариант с авторским обособлением в распространенном предложении: Против музыки, **как таковой**, папа не то что ничего не имел, но главным образом она для него в доме и звучала. [Юлия Лавряшина. Улитка в тарелке (2011)]

Comment: C билетом из словаря пример? Обычно говорят об отсутствии билетов во множественном числе (здесь можно было "таковых").

Comment: Да,  лучше "за отсутствием таковых"

Answer (score 0):

**Как такового/такого, неизвестно, стоял ли Иисус на стене буквального храма, или это было лишь видение.**

Совершенно непонятно, какой смысл вы вкладываете в это предложение в целом и в "как такого (или такового)" в частности. Никакой подобной конструкции (уместной в данном случае) не встречается в русском языке и сложно представить, чтобы она могла встретиться в каком-либо местном диалекте.